# Определение JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. Друзья, правильно ли будет сказать что *JQuery* – это сборник готовых функций, которые мы можем для своих целей вызывать лишь одной строчкой вместо десятков строк кода?
2. В коде версии 2.2.1 слово `function` встречается 601 раз – значит ли это, что в этом файле ровно 601 инструмент для облегчения нашей работы?
3. И можно ли безболезненно стереть из исходного файла JQuery неиспользуемые для конкретного сайта функции, дабы уменьшить вес файла?

Answer (score -1):

1. Не совсем. Ощутимая часть современного js длиннее аналога на jQuery раза в полтора и быстрее раз в 10-15
2. Однозначно нет
3. Большую часть функций вы можете стереть, но многие из них используются другими функциями, а часть - вообще ядро jquery (подкапотная магия, за счет которой оно работает в 10-15 раз медленнее нативного кода)

Comment: Каковы ваши доказательства , что Jquery работает в 10-15 раз медленнее нативного кода? Да, jquery помедленнее, ибо обертка, но откуда такие мутированные сбивающие с толку показатели?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский за точными цифрами вам сюда https://jsperf.com . начните, например,с `$`, `querySelector` и  `getElemetn(s)By...`

Comment: Нет, это вам туда. А дезинформировать о такой производительности - не надо ......... вот вам миллион итераций https://jsfiddle.net/g7nnduod/  на которой максимум в 3 раза...... **миллион** итераций, Карл!

Comment: @АлексейШиманский [ваш же пример](https://jsfiddle.net/g7nnduod/2/) - 
jQuery: 1164
querySelector: 368  ваши три раза
getElementById: 62  мои 18 раз

Comment: Ага, только не учтен факт того, что по идентификаторам выборка происходит реже (почти никогда), происходит как правило по группам элементов, к которым необходимо применить некие операции: банально поменять цвет. А для этого в ванильном js приходится гонять еще один цикл. https://jsfiddle.net/d6fk63dh/1/  ...... А если еще дополнительная выборка и фильтрация - то вдвойне. И ни о каком 10-15 раз говорить просто не приходится....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский О господи, неужели это правда? jQuery медленнее не в 10-15 раз, а всего в 3-5? Неужели? Немедленно всё бросаю и бегу втыкать во все свои проекты)

Comment: Ну да. примерно в 3...и то в зависимости от задач...в зависимости от выбранных путей решения и того меньше.... Напомню, что я сразу написал, что да, jquery медленнее. И это вполне логично и закономерно. Но не на столько ужасно. Если учесть тот факт, что в проектах не используются столь масштабные итерации в миллион, а всё обстоит гораздо проще, то, в итоге, получается некая экономия на спичках и не столь трагично, как вы это выдали.¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Выбирая, будете вы использовать jQuery или нет, вы выбираете на чьих спичках будете экономить - на ваших или на ваших юзеров.

Comment: Даааа, обработка 0.002 сек вместо 0,001сек это таааак критииично! Всё. надо срочно сообщить, чтобы все забросили фреймворки, cms, библиотеки во всех языках и немедля писали только на нативном ЯП. Нужно тотчас же писать президенту, чтоб издал закон об их запрещении и казнили прилюдно всех, кто не пишет на нативном языке иначе это преступление против всего человечества. Преступление вселенского масштаба я бы даже сказал. кошмар....\*facepalm\*